# Use Google Maps to show 2 markers with GIVEN lat/lng?

Tags: google-maps

I researched the Maps Api and it's pretty complicated for me..and I didn't find what I want.

I wrote a php program that does some gps coordinate manipulation and returns me 2 sets of latitude and longitude value ready to use. All I want is to generate a map showing 2 markers for these 2 places, with a straight line between them.

One pair of LAT/LNG value is different each time but for sure somewhere in US, and the other pair is random, can be anywhere in the world. (and hence, maybe the zoom level should adjust accordingly)

How should I implement this? Thanks a lot!

---

edit:

I have created this map with 2 markers, code:

echo '
    function initialize() {
    var pos_query = new google.maps.LatLng('.$decimal_latitude.','.$decimal_longitude.');
    var pos_tim = new google.maps.LatLng('.$result_tim_lat.','.$result_tim_lon.');

```
// var latlngbounds = new GLatLngBounds();
// latlngbounds.extend(pos_query);
// latlngbounds.extend(pos_tim);

var myOptions = {
 zoom: 5,  
 center: pos_tim,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
 mapTypeControl: false,
streetViewControl: false

};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);

//---> map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter(), map.getBoundsZoomLevel(latlngbounds));

var marker_query = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: pos_query, 
  map: map,
  title:"Your query location"});   

var marker_tim = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: pos_tim, 
  map: map,
  title:"Tim Horton"});
}
</script>';
```

However, I want to auto-adjust the zoom level and center of map using the code in comment.
But it doesnt work (the map doesnt show up)

I guess Im using V3 and the code in the comment part is older version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the Maps API's will do what your asking easily. You should read this [Google Maps API-Jscript](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html)

This will get you started.

This is the actual [API reference](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html) and is where you will find Maps, Controls, Overlays and Services. Pay special attention to the Overlays section, this is what you need to place your points on a map as well as custom images or graphics. The rest is programming. If you have specific questions regrading programming your best bet is to try some of this in your code and come back with code examples of what you're trying. Hope this helps.